# How to change the color of polygon's edge in for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

There are multiple polygons and for each of them I want to change the color and width of a left edge like fig 2. The first code which is for single polygon works properly. But I am wondering what's the problem with second code which I just put the first code in for loop.

Fig 1. initial polygon

[image]

fig 2. desired polygon with red line

[image]

```
# first code:


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pixels = 600
my_dpi = 100

one_coord = [[-150,-200],[300,-200],[300,0],[150,200],[-150,200]]


fig = plt.figure(figsize=( pixels/my_dpi,  pixels/my_dpi),facecolor='k', dpi=my_dpi)  


plt.axes([0,0,1,1])

rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
polygon = plt.Polygon(one_coord,color='w')
plt.gca().add_patch(polygon)

plt.axis('off')
plt.axis([-300,300,-300,300])

vertex_number = 5
vertex = np.zeros((vertex_number, 2, 2))
for i in range(vertex_number-1):   #rang(4), (0,1,2,3)
    vertex[i] = one_coord[i:i+2]  #(0:2) to (3:5)
vertex[4,0,:] = one_coord[-1][:]
vertex[4,1,:] = one_coord[0][:]

plt.plot(vertex[4,:,0],vertex[4,:,1], linewidth=5, color='r')

plt.savefig('figure1/4.jpg',dpi=my_dpi)
```

```
# Second code:

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pixels = 600
my_dpi = 100
num_geo=4

one_coord = np.array([[[-150, -200], [300, -200], [300, 0], [150, 200], [-150, 200]],
                  [[-300, -200], [200, -300], [200, -50], [200, 300], [-150, 200]],
                  [[-140, -230], [350, -260], [350, 0], [140, 200], [-180, 220]],
                  [[-180, -240], [370, -270], [370, 0], [170, 200], [-190, 230]]])

for i in range(4):
    geo =one_coord[i, :, :]
    print(one_coord[i])
    fig = plt.figure(num_geo, figsize=(pixels/my_dpi, pixels/my_dpi), 
                     facecolor='k', dpi=my_dpi)  
    plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
    rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
    plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
    polygon = plt.Polygon(one_coord[i],color='w')
    plt.gca().add_patch(polygon)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.axis([-300,300,-300,300])
    plt.close()
    vertex_number = 5

vertex = np.zeros((4,vertex_number,2, 2))

for j in range(num_geo):
    one_coord[j]

for k in range(vertex_number-1):   #rang(4), (0,1,2,3)
    vertex[j] = one_coord[j][k:k+2]  #(0:2) to (3:5)
    vertex[j,4,0,:] = one_coord[j][-1][:]
    vertex[j,4,1,:] = one_coord[j][0][:]


    plt.plot( vertex[j,:,0], vertex[j,:,1], linewidth=5, color='r')

    plt.savefig('figureBc/%d.jpg' % i, dpi=my_dpi)
    plt.close()
```

Comment: There are some typos in first code. Can you update it?

Comment: I updated the code.